# Xcode debugger documentation missing

Tags: xcode, debugging, data-formatters

Is anyone else having trouble navigating to the Xcode Debugging Guide?  I get redirected to a generic page when trying to get there through the Xcode documentation links in Xcode 4.0.2.

I have used GDB before, but I need to find out about Objective-c extensions and data formatters.

If someone can send me a link to good documentation, I would appreciate it.